# dell poweredge r210 II mix memory

Tags: configuration, memory, dell-poweredge

I have Dell PowerEdge R210 II server with 4Gb of memory installed. And I also have 8Gb memory module. I replaced 4Gb with 8Gb – server is working ok. But mixing memory in different ways got error "Unsupported memory configuration. DIMM mismatch across slots detected".

How can I install them both to get 12Gb of memory?

P.S. From server documentation: "Memory modules of different sizes can be mixed in sockets 1 to 4 (for example, 2 GB and 4 GB), but all populated channels must have identical configurations."

Comment: exactly what kind of memory modules do you have? two 2 gb modules, and one 8 gb module?

Comment: one module of 4Gb and one module of 8Gb

Comment: What are the specifications on the memory modules? Are **both** buffered or registered?

Comment: 1) ECC, UNBUFFERED, 4 GB 2) ECC, UNBUFFERED, 8 GB

Comment: According tp page 26 on <A href="http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=dell%20r210%20ii%20user%20manual&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CEMQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.advania.is%2Flibrary%2FFiles%2F1.-Vefverslun-PDF%2FMidlaegar-lausnir%2FPowerEdge%2Fr-210-2-technical-guide.pdf&ei=GyuAUKftGpLQ4QS-sIGACA&usg=AFQjCNE-1MLGrTzejlOrIMj--mp6vwRZUw">the Poweredge R210 II user manual</a> that is the right type of memory.  The only point worth noting is that for dual rank memory modules with two modules per channel the max speed drop to 1066Mhz. I would expect the BIOS to fall back in speed though.

Answer (score 2):

you will notice that each of the slots is either white or black. the white slots are the first channel, and the black slots are the second channel. also, [the manual](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/Per210II/en/HOM/PDF/R210.pdf) implies that a channel can be unpopulated.

therefore, you should install your 2 ram modules in slots 1 and 3, i.e. the two white slots.

Comment: The same error "Unsupported memory configuration. DIMM mismatch across slots detected"

Answer (score 0):

I have a R210 II sitting here that's running fine using 24GB RAM (16GB + 8GB). No warnings or problems. Is your server running the latest firmware?